Проблема с подключением кошелька tonkeeper в ton blueprint
Работаю в фреймворке ton blueprint. У меня есть рабочий контракт и деплой скрипт. При запуске в консоли я считываю qr code для подключения кошелька tonkeeper, после сканирования я получаю сообщение в консоли, что отсутствует манифест ton-connect, чего быть не должно, потому что он должен быть внутри фреймворка. Ниже представлю код ошибки:
Scan the QR code in your wallet or open the link...[TON_CONNECT_SDK] Wallet message received: {
  event: 'connect_error',
  payload: {
    code: 2,
    message: "Can't get https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ton-defi-org/tonconnect-manifest-temp/main/tonconnect-manifest.json"
  },
  id: 77
}

